# scrreprt: No extra page per chapter

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, koma-script

Is it possible to configure koma-script's scrreprt so, that it does not create a page only for the chapter information on the start of a new chapter? I am aware that scrartcl does not do this with part's but I'd like to use scrreprt.

**Update:** Turns out that I confused

```
\include{}
```

with

```
\input{}
```

Include starts a new page for every included file....

Comment: I've closed this based on the edits: seems to be a misunderstanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me. No extra pages for chapters:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\section{B}
some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. I mixed up \include with \input. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, cannot add comments at the moment, less reputation.)

Perhaps I didn't get the point, but in this example my chapter D starts at a new page:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}
\section{B}
some text
\section{C}
some text

\chapter{D}
\section{E}
some text
\section{F}
some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer.

Comment: @Christoph It is normal that scrreprt starts a new page for every chapter. My problem, that the chapter headline was on a single page, turned out to be because of `\include`.

Comment: @Joseph Wright -- That's why I already explained that in the round braces in my so-called answer.